# clang-format skips #if 0 sections. Is there an option to fix that?

Tags: c++, c, clang-format

The sections between #if 0, #endif are ignored (unaltered with -i) by clang-format. I am not sure whether this is a bug or a feature. Assuming this is a feature, is there an option to change that behavior?

Currently, I use a clunky workaround: I replace #if 0 with #if _ (after verifying that there is no #if _ in the source), I format and then change #if _ back to #if 0.

Comment: Should you be keeping the `#if 0` / `#endif` blocks in the first place?  Assuming the answer is "yes", then globally replace `#if 0` with `#if 1 /* 0 */`, run the formatter, and then undo the edit.  Adding the comment allows you to identify which lines were `#if 0` before you edited it.

Comment: Why do you have `#if 0`’d our code? It’ll rot a lot less if you `if constexpr (false) {…}` it. But it’s still dubious.